# PHP copy folder from another place on ftp to new destination

Tags: php, mysql

I have made this script to generate 3 folders with Random names, and in the end, I paste a complete folder I have placed another place inside the ftp.

It really works great with the folders, but I can't make the copy paste in the end folder!

Can you explain how to fix it?

```
     <?php $tags = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT domaine FROM `domains` ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1; ") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
             while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($tags)) 
                         {            
                             $domainresul =  $row['domaine'];
                         } 

                            function random_string($length) {
                                $key = '';
                                $keys = array_merge(range(0, 9), range('a', 'z'));
                                for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                                $key .= $keys[array_rand($keys)];
                                }

                                return $key;
                            }


                            $file = "index.php";
                            $content = $sideindhold;


                            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


                            $ftp_server = "xxx"; // virtuelt doamin
                            $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
                            $ftp_user_name = "xxx"; // bruger jeg har opsat på min xampp, med rettigheder til example.com
                            $ftp_user_pass = "xxx";
                            $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

                            // $root="url/phptest";
                            $root = $domainresul;




                            /* **************************************** */
                            /* create a stream context telling PHP to overwrite the file */
                            $options = array('ftp' => array('overwrite' => true));
                            $stream = stream_context_create($options);
                            /* **************************************** */


                            // check connection
                            echo "<center>";
                            if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) {
                            echo '<div style="background-color:red;padding:10px;color:#fff;font-size:16px;">';
                            echo "FTP connection has failed!";
                            echo "Attempted to connect to <b>$ftp_server</b> for user <b>$ftp_user_name</b>";
                            echo '</div>';
                            } else {

                            $foldername1 = random_string(4);
                            $foldername2 = random_string(3);
                            $foldername3 = random_string(2);



                            $directory = "$root/$foldername1";

                            if (ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $directory)) {

                            $directory = "$root/$foldername1/$foldername2";

                            if (ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $directory)) {

                            $directory = "$root/$foldername1/$foldername2/$foldername3";


                            if (ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $directory)) {
                            /* **************************************** */
                            /* and finally, put the contents */
                            $hostname2 = "ftp://" . $ftp_user_name . ":" . $ftp_user_pass . "@" . $ftp_server . "/";
                 $hostname = "ftp://" . $ftp_user_name . ":" . $ftp_user_pass . "@" . $ftp_server . "/" . $directory . "/";


                   $src = $hostname2 . "xxx.xxx/se";
                   $dst = $hostname;

                   echo $src;
                   echo $dst;

                   shell_exec("cp -r $src $dest");

                 /* **************************************** */

             }
         }
     } else {
         echo '<div style="background-color:red;padding:10px;color:#fff;font-size:16px">';
         echo "Could not create directory: <b>$directory</b>";
         echo '</div>';
     }
 }
 echo "</center>";  } ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried `cp -R`? That is using upper case `R`. I assume that you’re on Linux, which is very case sensitive.

Comment: When i try, it show echo "Array" .. and nothing happens.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the `cp -R` suggestion, so you must have an error before then. Throw in a few more echo statements (`echo 1;`, `echo 2;` etc) to see where the error occurs. If it echoes `Array` then you are printing a variable which contains an array. You need to find out which `echo` statement is doing that.

Comment: i have find it now! my script work grate it make the random foldernames and find the korrekt place for file destanation. but it don't make a copy of the folder and place it in the end of mig new url.

Comment: Did you try to change the `cp -R` command?

Comment: yes i have try :)

Comment: Does `cp` work with ftp connections? I think you need `rcp` or similar. If you use `rcp` then the `r` should be lower case.

Comment: Can i make the copy another Way then cp  - r? Maby like copy($,$) ? I Think the cp-r don't wotk for me